# Can't figure out how one trick for defining a limit works

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am puzzled by the following solution for finding a limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\cos x -1 \over \sin^2 x+x\log(1+x)}= \lim_{x \to 0}{{{\cos x-1} \over x^2}x^2 \over {\sin^2x \over x^2}x^2+x{\log(1+x)\over x}x}\stackrel{?}= {\frac 12 \over 1+1}=4$$
I have taken this example from some paper.
The transition between the second and the third step is far from being obvious for me.

Could someone explain me why numerator and denominator are evaluated as such after the transformation performed in the second step?

Comment: [Algebra of limits](http://sun.iwu.edu/~lstout/limitTheorems/node3.html).

Comment: @boywholived I know these ruled, but see ain't no application of them in this example

Comment: Then I got the question wrong. Are you having trouble finding limits of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $\frac{\ln{1+x}}{x}$?

Comment: $\cos x-1 = -2 \sin^2 (x/2)$, so $\dfrac{\cos x-1}{x^2} = -\dfrac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{4 (x/2)^2} = ...$

Comment: @boywholived The term in numerator equals $\frac 12$, I can't see, why it is so. Neither for the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it should be:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}x^2}{x^2 \left( \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}+\frac{\log (1+x)}{x} \right)} = \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{1+1}.
$$

Comment: Should I cross out $x^2$?

Comment: Of course you should!

Comment: Ok, so twice L'Hôpital for ${\cos x-1 \over x^2}$ really ships $-\frac 12$

Comment: It is a very popular limit that follows from $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$.